# how to get customer attributes in magento2?

Tags: php-5.4, system.xml, customer-attribute, magento2-dev-beta

I'm displaying `customer attributes` on **Multiselect Textbox** in General Tab.

In Magento 1.0 simply getting Customer Attributes by using below code

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $attributes = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_attribute_collection')
            // remove filter to allow default address ID, etc.
            ->addVisibleFilter();
        $result = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if (($label = $attribute->getFrontendLabel()))
                $result[$attribute->getId()] = $label;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

And add the attributes to `system.xml` file

```
<fieldname translate="label">
    <label>Customer Attributes</label>
    <frontend_type>checkboxes</frontend_type>
    <source_model>Test/source_customer_attribute</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
</fieldname>
```

From Magento 2.0 i don't know how to get Customer Attributes? Can you please Suggest me how to get customer attributes.

I have created system.xml file and it's related resource file.

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
             <label>General</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <group id="customersdata" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Customer Attributes</label>
                <field id="allow" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Customer Attributes</label>
                    <source_model>Training\Test\Model\Config\Source\Customers</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Training\Test\Model\Config\Source\Customers**

```
<?php

namespace Training\Test\Model\Config\Source;

use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

class Customers implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    protected $_options;

    protected $_customerCollections;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Resource\Customer\Collection  $customerCollection)
    {
        //$this->_customerCollections = $customerCollection;
    }

    public function toOptionArray($isMultiselect = false)
    {

        //$attributes = \Magento\Customer\

       /* if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = $this->$_customerCollections->loadData()->toOptionArray(false);
        }*/

        $options = $this->_options;
        if (!$isMultiselect) {
            array_unshift($options, ['value' => '', 'label' => __('--Please Select--')]);
        }

        return $options;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `Customers.php` Class like below.

**Training\Test\Model\Config\Source\Customers**

```
<?php

namespace Training\Test\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Customer\Model;

class Customers implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        //\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $interface
    ) {
       // $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
       $this->objectManager = $interface;
    }


    public function toOptionArray( $isMultiselect = false)
    {
        $customer_attributes = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getAttributes();

        $attributesArrays = array();

           foreach($customer_attributes as $cal=>$val){
               $attributesArrays[] = array(
                   'label' => $cal,
                   'value' => $cal
               );
           }

        return $attributesArrays;
    }

}
```

Comment: Even if this might work, it's not a good practice to use `Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface` directly except when in factories.  Instead you should inject in the constructor an instance of `\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory` named `customerFactory` and call `$attributes = $this->customerFactory->create()->getAttributes()`

Comment: @Marius, here `create()` acts like `getModel()`, So what we have to use for `getSingleton() ` object.

Comment: Use `get` instead of `create` to get it as a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me in Magento 2.4.4

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as CustomerModel;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class AllowedAttributes implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        protected CustomerModel $customer
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray(): array
    {
        $options = [];

        try {
            $attributes = $this->customer->getAttributes();

            foreach($attributes as $attributeCode) {
                    $options[] = [
                    'label' => $attributeCode->getStoreLabel(),
                    'value' => $attributeCode->getAttributeCode(),
                ];
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) { }

        return $options;
    }
}
```